# Include EMF file in MigraDoc / PDFSharp

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

How does one include a EMF image in a PDF generated by MigraDoc or PDFSharp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but I presume you load EMF images just like BMP images. (BTW: you can use pages from PDF files just like BMP images, too).
The GDI+ build may not support this, but the WPF build should be able to handle EMF files.